# Problem with XML parsing on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, soap

When I receive data from web service my NSMutableData is filled with following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetWeatherResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET"><GetWeatherResult>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;
&lt;CurrentWeather&gt;
  &lt;Location&gt;BERLIN MUNICIPAL AIRPORT, NH, United States (KBML) 44-35N 71-11W 345M&lt;/Location&gt;
  &lt;Time&gt;Oct 19, 2010 - 03:52 AM EDT / 2010.10.19 0752 UTC&lt;/Time&gt;
  &lt;Wind&gt; Calm:0&lt;/Wind&gt;
  &lt;Visibility&gt; 10 mile(s):0&lt;/Visibility&gt;
  &lt;SkyConditions&gt; clear&lt;/SkyConditions&gt;
  &lt;Temperature&gt; 23.0 F (-5.0 C)&lt;/Temperature&gt;
  &lt;DewPoint&gt; 21.0 F (-6.1 C)&lt;/DewPoint&gt;
  &lt;RelativeHumidity&gt; 91&lt;/RelativeHumidity&gt;
  &lt;Pressure&gt; 29.83 in. Hg (1010 hPa)&lt;/Pressure&gt;
  &lt;Status&gt;Success&lt;/Status&gt;
&lt;/CurrentWeather&gt;</GetWeatherResult></GetWeatherResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

So when I search for "CurrentWeather" parser can't find it because of &qt, &lt etc. How to fix my NSMutableData to have normal values (<, > etc.)?

COMPLETE CODE

```
#import "DemoWebServiceConsumeViewController.h"

@implementation DemoWebServiceConsumeViewController

@synthesize cityName;
@synthesize activityIndicator;
@synthesize location;

- (IBAction) hideKeyboard{
    [cityName resignFirstResponder];
}

- (IBAction) buttonClicked: (id)sender{

    [cityName resignFirstResponder];    

    NSString *soapMsg = 
    [NSString stringWithFormat:
     @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
     "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
     "<soap:Body>"
     "<GetWeather xmlns=\"http://www.webserviceX.NET\">"
     "<CityName>%@</CityName>"
     "<CountryName>%@</CountryName>"
     "</GetWeather>"
     "</soap:Body>"
     "</soap:Envelope>", cityName.text, @"united states"
     ];

    NSLog(soapMsg);    

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: 
                  @"http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //---set the headers---
    // here copy method name to be called SOAP Action read from WS description
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMsg length]];
    [req addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" 
    forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [req addValue:@"http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetWeather" 
    forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [req addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    //---set the HTTP method and body---
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [req setHTTPBody: [soapMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    [activityIndicator startAnimating];    

    conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    if (conn) {
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }  
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection 
didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *) response {
    [webData setLength: 0];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection 
    didReceiveData:(NSData *) data {
    [webData appendData:data];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection 
  didFailWithError:(NSError *) error {
    [webData release];    
    [connection release];
}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection {
    NSLog(@"DONE READING WEATHER WEB SERVICE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);
    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] 
                        initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] 
                        length:[webData length] 
                        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //---shows the XML---
    NSLog(theXML);  

    [theXML release]; 

    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];    

    if (xmlParser)
    {
        [xmlParser release];
    }
    xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: webData];
                [xmlParser setDelegate:self];   
                [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
                [xmlParser parse];


    [connection release];
    [webData release];
}

//---when the start of an element is found---
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser 
    didStartElement:(NSString *) elementName 
    namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI 
    qualifiedName:(NSString *) qName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *) attributeDict {


    NSLog(elementName);
    if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"GetWeatherResult"])
    {
        if (!soapResults)
        {
            soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        }
        elementFound = YES;
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Location"])
    {
        elementFound = YES;
    }   
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (elementFound)
    {
        [soapResults appendString: string];
    }   
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
        didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
        namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
        qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"GetWeatherResult"])
    {   
        NSLog(soapResults);        
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                              initWithTitle:@"Current Temperature!"                                                                                   
                              message:soapResults 
                              delegate:self  
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        [soapResults setString:@""];
        elementFound = FALSE; 
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: can you post the part of the code where you do this conversion please? the error could be due to an incorrect encoding set, but without the code is hard to say.

Comment: Indeed; we need to see how you retrieve the data before we can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've edited your question so it shows what I think is what you meant to paste.  It looks like the web service is encapsulating a whole XML file as a string inside another XML tag.  So what you need to do is get the entire content of the `<GetWeatherResult>` XML tag as a single string.  I think NSXMLParser will automatically substitute the correct characters in place of `&gt;` etc.

Having got that string, you need to pass it into another NSXMLParser to parse the content of it.

Comment: I added new NSXMLParser *weatherXmlParser; in header file. And in didEndElement method when I get XML that is valid I store it in a NSMutableString *soapResults; variable. And try to parse it: if (weatherXmlParser)
  {
   [weatherXmlParser release];
  }
  weatherXmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: soapResults];
  [weatherXmlParser setDelegate:self]; 
  [weatherXmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
  [weatherXmlParser parse]; But I get the following error "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.".

Comment: You need to convert soapResults to an NSData.

Comment: I am sorry for I am boring :(. I Added "NSData *wData = [soapResults dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
  NSLog(wData);
", but I receive new error: "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
". And after this parse method is not invoked.

Comment: you can't NSLog a data object like that.  You have to do `NSLog(@"%@", wData);`

Comment: is there any way with out double parsing the data for this problem, because i am also facing same problem

Comment: @MaheshBabu:  No. It's the easiest way because fundamentally you do have one XML string encapsulated inside another.